# Diem CLI, txn_acc_seq, Transaction not available

Tags: command-line-interface, diem

In the Diem (Libra) CLI:

```
libra% query txn_acc_seq 9f49240376634fdb3277adb91ed075ccfeff8d26d71a28d49958d51711a1e01d 0 true
>> Getting committed transaction by account and sequence number
Transaction not available
```

I get a similar input also with different sequence numbers (1,2,3,...)

I would expect this command to show the transactions associated to this address, why is this not happening?

Additional info:
Just to confirm that the account did transactions in the past:

```
libra% query balance 9f49240376634fdb3277adb91ed075ccfeff8d26d71a28d49958d51711a1e01d
Balance is: 416.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txn_acc_seq | ts` — Get the **committed** transaction by account and sequence number.

So it's only gonna work for transactions that you've sent.

If you wanna get received transactions you should use events

like this

```
query event 9f49240376634fdb3277adb91ed075ccfeff8d26d71a28d49958d51711a1e01d received 0 true 100
```

You can't get a mint transaction from CLI

Mint is not a transaction if you don't have a faucet account, if you check `/client/src/client_proxy.rs` you can see that mint is just a GET request to the faucet server

if you have a faucet account

`Some(_) => self.mint_coins_with_local_faucet_account`

if you don't have a faucet account

`None => self.mint_coins_with_faucet_service`

`http://{faucet_server}?amount={num_coins}&address={receiver}`

And the server make a mint request

You can find the source code for it in `libra/docker/mint/server.py`

`"a m {} {}".format(address, amount / (10 ** 6)))`

which will use `self.mint_coins_with_local_faucet_account` in the client

And mint itself `mint_to_address in libra_account.mvir` doesn't emit any events

Comment: Is there a way to query also the mint events?
Apparently “query event …” is not returning those.